# Capturing ARSCNView with virtual objects - iOS

Tags: ios, arkit, agora.io, arscnview

I have an ARSCNView with virtual objects drawn. The virtual objects are drawn on the user's face. 
The session has the following configuration:

```
let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading

sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

This ARSCNView is part of a video call. If we send back the pixel buffer like below,

```
 public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    videoSource.sendBuffer(frame.capturedImage, timestamp: frame.timestamp)
 }
```

The virtual objects are not shown to my caller.

One of the things I tried is, to not rely on `ARSessionDelegate`'s callback but use DispatchSourceTimer to send events.

```
func startCaptureView() {  
  // Timer with 0.1 second interval
  timer.schedule(deadline: .now(), repeating: .milliseconds(100))
  timer.setEventHandler { [weak self] in
    // Turn sceneView data into UIImage
    guard let sceneImage: CGImage = self?.sceneView.snapshot().cgImage else {
      return
    }

    self?.videoSourceQueue.async { [weak self] in
       if let buffer: CVPixelBuffer = ImageProcessor.pixelBuffer(forImage: sceneImage) {
             self?.videoSource.sendBuffer(buffer, timestamp: Double(mach_absolute_time()))
        }
    }
  }

  timer.resume()
}
```

The caller receives the data slowly with a choppy video experience and the images are not of the right size.

Any suggestions on how to send data about the virtual object along with the captured frame?

Reference: https://medium.com/agora-io/augmented-reality-video-conference-6845c001aec0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the Virtual objects are not appearing is because ARKit provides only the raw image, so `frame.capturedImage` is the image captured by the camera, without any of the SceneKit rendering. To pass the rendered video you will need to implement an offscreen `SCNRenderer` and pass the pixel buffer to Agora's SDK.

I would recommend you check out the Open Source framework [AgoraARKit](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-ARKit). I wrote the framework and it implements [Agora.io Video SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/downloads) and [ARVideoKit](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit) as dependancies. [ARVideoKit](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit) is a popular library that implements an off-screen renderer and provides the rendered pixel buffer.

The library implements WorldTracking by default. If you want to extend the `ARBroadcaster` class to implement faceTracking you could use this code:

```
import ARKit

class FaceBroadcaster : ARBroadcaster {

    // placements dictionary
    var faceNodes: [UUID:SCNNode] = [:]           // Dictionary of faces

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    override func setARConfiguration() {
        print("setARConfiguration")        // Configure ARKit Session
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        // run the config to start the ARSession
        self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        self.arvkRenderer?.prepare(configuration)
    }

    // anchor detection
    override func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        super.renderer(renderer, didAdd: node, for: anchor)
        guard let sceneView = renderer as? ARSCNView, anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return }
        /*
         Write depth but not color and render before other objects.
         This causes the geometry to occlude other SceneKit content
         while showing the camera view beneath, creating the illusion
         that real-world faces are obscuring virtual 3D objects.
         */
        let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)!
        faceGeometry.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
        let occlusionNode = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
        occlusionNode.renderingOrder = -1

        let contentNode = SCNNode()
        contentNode.addChildNode(occlusionNode)
        node.addChildNode(contentNode)
        faceNodes[anchor.identifier] = node
    }
}
```